# Laravel - Use ID's to represent car makes in a vehicle field but return the full name in view

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

Is this classed as a belongs to / belongstomany / hasmany etc?

I have a table in my DB which contains all car makes:

```
ID | name | display_name

1  | audi | Audi
2  | bmw  | BMW
```

I also have a vehicles table:

```
ID | VRM     | make

1  | HW55VRM | 2
2  | VN62HHS | 1
```

What I wish to do is when returning all of the vehicles in my repository like so:

```
public function getAll()
{
    return Vehicle::all();
}
```

What I wish to do is convert the make value to match that in the makes table and return the display name for it. So in my view I can simply call the display name as the text value.

Answer (score 0):

You didn`t show relations between vehicles and makers, so for example it is like

```
class Vehicle
{
  public function maker()
  {
      return $this->hasOne('Makers');
  }
}
```

Then in blade

```
@foreach(Vehicle::with('maker')->get() as $vehicle)
    {{ $vehicle->maker->display_name }} {{ $vehicle->VRM }}
@endforeach
```